# Awkward rep-calculation?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit

As I understand it, "accepts" are immune against the rep-cap, so with 3 accepts, I should be able to reach 245 points for that day?

How come I didn't get points for my last upvote?!

http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/8281/soq.png

---

Hmm.. could it be the case that some "cheat-detection-system" kicked in. There was this guy that posted 5 (fairly unrelated) questions in one stack overflow question. I told him that it was bad practice and made it harder for the casual googler to find what he was looking for and urged him to split it up into several questions. After that I answered two more of his questions and he probably upvoted and accepted them within an hour I believe...

- [Ide style program running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002976/ide-style-program-running)
- [How do I make a button that when pressed stops an internal program from running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054860/how-do-i-make-a-button-that-when-pressed-stops-an-internal-program-from-running)
- [How do I catch a java io printstream place its output in a jeditorpane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055303/how-do-i-catch-a-java-io-printstream-place-its-output-in-a-jeditorpane)

---

Last activity according to `/reputation`

```
-- 2010-10-28 rep +53   = 19994     
 2   4049955 (10)
 2   4003001 (10)
 2   4050158 (10)
 2   4050472 (10)
 2   4050472 (10)
 2   4050534 (10)
 2   4050534 (10)
 1   4050472 (15)
 2   4050158 (10)
 2   4050534 (10)
 2   4051368 (10)
 2   4050158 (10)
 2   4054586 (10)
 2   4054586 (10)
 2   4054586 (10)
 1   4054586 (15)
 2   4054586 (10)
 2   4054586 (10)
 2   4050158 (10)
 1   4050158 (15)
 2   4054922 (10)
 2   4055338 (10)
 1   4054922 (15)
 2   4054922 (10)
-- 2010-10-29 rep +260  = 20254     

** total rep 20254 :)
```

---

My [other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68944/reputation-calculation-can-accepts-count-towards-the-rep-cap) is related.

Comment: Could you post that day's activity from your rep audit? http://www.stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: done. (pad....)

Comment: It looks like it's an issue with the recent activity page. It doesn't handle deleted posts very well. You had four accepted answers (there are four +15s on there), and ended the day +260. You can ask to have your rep recalc'd, but it will actually go down just a bit if you do (due to deleted posts).

Comment: Uhm, ok, I'm not sure I get it... I don't think any of my questions/answers have been deleted?

Comment: this could happen if you answered a question and got upvoted but the entire question was deleted, taking your ansewr with it.

Answer (score 1):

You've earned 2 votes (20 rep) for an answer that day. But the original question has been deleted later the same day. Or it was actually yourself who deleted the answer with those 2 votes earned the same day.

Try remembering which questions you've answered the night before :)

If it's bothering you, a rep recalc should fix that. Mail team@stackoverflow.com or flag for mod attention on any of your answers and request there.

Comment: Aha, so basically, a question that I answered must have been deleted, or I must have forgotten that I deleted an answer... Makes sense I suppose...

Comment: Only the same day! (UTC) :) Deleted answers/questions which are dated at day before today won't affect the daily rep like that. You could however see it by a decrease in total score in /reputation overview.

Comment: Aha, okey. Is the "total rep" in the `/reputation` page my "real" reputation? The one that I would get if someone recomputed my reputation?

Comment: @aioobe - yes. This takes into account all the questions/answers that have been deleted.

Comment: @ChrisF, ouch! I would loose 300 points! :-(

Comment: @aioobe - you've already "lost" those points through deleted posts, it's just that the headline figure doesn't change when posts are deleted.

Comment: That's a shame actually. Then there is an incentive to *not* delete an answer that is wrong but that has gotten a few upvotes.

Comment: Usually those are closed questions (not real question, offtopic, etc) which are voted for deletion. You can see them by 10k tools.