# Reputation calculation: can accepts count towards the rep-cap?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit

I really can't find a good reference on how the reputation cap works. (If this is an exact dupe, I'm happy!)

Suppose I get 17 upvotes and 2 accepts, then I have +200.

What happens if I then get one more up-vote? Will it increase the rep to +210, or will the rep stay at +200?

(From experience I really thought that it would increase to +210 (and that the effective cap was at +230 due to the two accepts). Today however, I was surprised to see that this didn't seem to be the case.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reputation system was changed. It's real simple now:

- You can get up to 200 reputation from votes only.
- You can get infinite reputation from other sources.
- The order in which you get the reputation doesn't matter, with the exception of downvotes and upvotes: in fact, if you get downvoted after reaching the 200 cap you will be stuck at 198; if you are downvoted before, you can still get at 200.

Comment: However the order in which you lose reputation still matters. E.g. if you get 20 upvotes, one downvote and one upvote again, you'll have 200 rep. If you get 21 upvotes and then one downvote, you'll have 198.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @aioobe: what do you mean a reference? My post is correct, except for the what sepp2k said =)

Comment: @aioobe - I can vouch that this is how it works, any downvotes at any point in the day, regardless of when the cap was reached...that rep can be "reclaimed" by later upvotes in the day.

Comment: (It still contradicts [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68934/awkward-rep-calculation) though... any idea why?)