# Strange reputation calculation (revisited)

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68944/reputation-calculation-can-accepts-count-towards-the-rep-cap/68946#68946) I should be able to get +262 rep for one day, if I have 200 from upvotes, 4 accepts and accepted an answer of one of my own questions.

However, I seem to be stuck at 242 today:

http://aoeu.se/so/strange_rep.png

Any idea why?

My `/reputation` looks like this:

```
 1   4204897 (2)
 2   4213262 (10)
 2   4213262 (10)
 2   4213632 (10)
 2   4213262 (10)
 1   4213854 (15)
 2   4213354 (10)
 1   4213262 (15)
 2   4213992 (5)
 2   4213992 (5)
 2   4214585 (10)
 2   4214717 (10)
 2   4214717 (10)
 2   4214585 (10)
 1   4214717 (15)
 2   4214585 (10)
 2   4215138 (10)
 2   4215138 (10)
 2   2757131 (10)
 2   4216005 (10)
 2   4216013 (10)
 2   4216013 (10)
 1   4216013 (15)
 2   4216013 (10)
 2   4216445 (10)
 2   4216445 (10)
-- 2010-11-18 rep +262  = 23239
```

Comment: `/reputation` looks right; you should be at exactly the cap now. The recent activity feed isn't showing credit for the two upvotes to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216414/read-remote-text-file-in-android/4216445#4216445), which is the last answer you got upvotes for

Comment: Right. Why isn't "Recent Activity"/"Reputation" showing that I got rep for those two upvotes?!

Comment: This is something you'll have to get used to once to start hitting the rep cap.  The rep for an answer can change due to changes in other questions you answered.  The query to calc actual rep is too expensive, that's why /reputation exists.

Comment: Well, I got the epic-badge today, so I'm quite used to hitting the rep-cap. But so basically you're saying that the reputation shown in Recent Activity is to be seen as a (possibly inaccurate) approximation?